mold growth in crawl space?
Mold growth in crawl space
We recently had some of our vinyl flooring swell. Since it was in the laundry room, I made a small cut to spray peroxide. Next thing I know there's mushrooms growing out of it. Needless to say, I cut the mushrooms, sprayed some more peroxide and it finally stopped. Now, 6 weeks later, other parts of the vinyl flooring are swelling up. This is around 2 feet from the first one. I took some pictures of the crawl space underneath the vinyl flooring, but I can't tell if that's mold growth (at least not based on the pictures I've seen online). This is an old house (1947 built) in the Piedmont/Charlotte metro area and I've always noticed puddles near the walls in the crawl space. I figured those puddles were common after heavy rain, but I'm not sure how much of it can contribute to mold growth. I'm not much of a DIYer especially for things like this, so would appreciate any guidance! Thanks y'all!pictures - https://imgur.com/a/JtOWINa

Nobody can say definitively. Test and find out. Also, figure out why the crawlspace is so moist... that's the root of the problem.
